# In C#, how to use a variable's contents to access an objects property

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook addin and am trying to avoid the world's largest switch. To get contact information, I am using items like: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ContactItem.EmailAddress 
Since there are many items, I would like to use a variable to select the item, like string myVariable="EmailAddress"; or string myVariable="FullName"; Then use ContactItem.myVariable. These items pulled from an xml file. I am drawing a blank and could use some help. Thank you.

Comment: Use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)

Comment: Assuming that the object in question is not just `dynamic`, use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) as @LucasTrzesniewski has commented. If, on the other hand, it *is* of type `dynamic`, we're in a completely different world, so check if reflection will work, and then come back to us if it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "the world's largest switch"? Share your code (or  some prototype that conveys what you're doing now) and we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create an extension method that checks the properties, by using reflection.

Though keep in mind some of the remarks from your start post :)

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

public static class ContactItemExtension
{
    public static object Get(this Outlook.ContactItem item, string property)
    {
        object result = null;
        if (item == null) {
            // default null
            return result;
        }
        var ctype = item.GetType();
        var cprop = ctype.GetProperty(property);
        if (cprop == null || cprop.GetGetMethod() == null) {
            // no property found or it doesn't have a get
            return result;
        }
        result = cprop.GetValue(item, null);
        return result;
    }
}
```

after which you can simple call, the Get method with the property name on top of any ContactItem

```
item.Get("EmailAddress1");
```

Comment: OK, I am trying reflection, much to learn. In the above sample code, item.GetType is throwing an exception. I will pursue that. What I meant by large switch statement is that there are some 50 properties in a contact, plus the user can add more. I create an xml file where the user can enter which contact properties to put into which cells in an excel template. I am off to learn more about reflection.

Comment: @IcepicklsThanks again for advice. I could not make an extension, as above, work. I have not given up but set that aside and am using a brute force method. Cycling through all properties and matching to the ones I want to insert into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry, inexperience here.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to loop through all available Contact properties to get non-null, non-blank values without knowing the name of the property?